# Using get variables to sort paginated content in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, pagination

I have a page which shows a table of paginated content. I also have a link to sort by date in ascending or descending order.

When I click a sort link, it adds the GET variables as expected. Unfortunately, it also removes the old GET variables, including the `page` for the pagination.

When I click a pagination link it doesn't remove any GET variables, due to the `{!! $results->appends(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::except('page'))->render() !!}` code I found on GitHub, intended to prevent this.

How can I do a similar thing to my links for sorting? The links appear in a format like `<a href="{{ route('admin.results.index', array('sort' => 'date', 'direction' => 'asc')) }}">ASC</a>`.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a similar question about pagination, sorting and filering here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215210/laravel-3-pagination-sorting-filtering?rq=1 Maybe this already helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code : 
`<a href="{{ route('admin.results.index', array('page' => Input::get('page'),'sort' => 'date', 'direction' => 'asc')) }}">ASC</a>`

just add 'page' parameter to your link

Comment: I had to append the page to the end of the array, otherwise the page variable switched position in the URL, but that answer worked perfectly.